# ARP request received by one end of ip-link peer and not the other

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ethernet, arp

I have created a network namespace `reflector` for the interface `v-ref`.
It is [peered](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ip-link.8.html) to the interface `v-test` in the default namespace:

```
sudo ip netns add reflector
sudo ip link add v-test type veth peer name v-ref
sudo ip link set v-ref netns reflector
```

The interfaces are assigned these IP addresses:

```
sudo ifconfig v-test 10.0.0.5/24 up
sudo ip netns exec reflector ifconfig v-ref 10.0.0.2/24 up
```

When ICMP packets are sent from `10.0.0.5` to `10.0.0.2`, tcpdump shows

```
01:09:21.169421 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.0.2 tell 10.0.0.5, length 28
01:09:21.169446 ARP, Reply 10.0.0.2 is-at d2:39:6a:33:cd:6b, length 28
01:09:21.169449 IP 10.0.0.5 > 10.0.0.2: ICMP echo request, id 6921, seq 1, length 64
01:09:21.169460 IP 10.0.0.2 > 10.0.0.5: ICMP echo reply, id 6921, seq 1, length 64
```

When, however, ICMP packets are sent from `10.0.0.2` to `10.0.0.5`,

```
sudo ip netns exec reflector ping -I v-ref 10.0.0.5
```

there is only an ARP request, and no ARP response, as tcpdump shows:

```
01:09:26.219301 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.0.5 tell 10.0.0.2, length 28
```

What is missing in this configuration for `10.0.0.2` to receive an ARP reply from `10.0.0.5`?

Comment: I you have to use "ping -I v-ref" for this to work, then chances are that the actual ARP answer is sent through an other interface. Do a complete experiment sandbox: use two namespaces, so you don't have routing problems which affect ARP.

Comment: yeah, that solved it. Now when pinging to the interface that is now in the sandbox namespace and was in default, the interface now replies.